# Как правильно разбить psd макет чтобы начать верстку?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Добрый день, взял свой первый макет, в принципе контент и footer ничего сложного из себя не представляют, но вот header меня заставил задуматься. Прикрепляю кусок макета. Подскажите как правильно разрезать данный header точбы его сверстать? Чем лучше header верстать div? Или таблицей?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

верстай блоками из разрезания тебе надо только лого вырезать, а так у тебя будет 4 блока
1-темная линия сверху
2-блок с надписью {title}страницы
3-основное лого, и то если шрифт стандартный то и его можно без картинки сделать.
4-последний блок с номерами телефонов

Answer (score 1):

как вижу сделал это с помощью фотошопа. Теперь сделай фон тот что белый прозрачным, после копируй каждую часть своего макета и сохраняй отдельно в формате png (если тебе фон не нужен) и вставляй как изображение и в стиле прописывай position: absolute и соответственно отступы от левого и верхнего краев. Поверь так проще)

Comment: >> Как правильно разбить **psd**  ...

>> как вижу сделал это с помощью фотошопа

Да вы кеп однако! :)

Comment: Ох как смешно. Есть множество других графических редакторов.